# What's an example of an ideal in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-n}]$ that is not principal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, examples-counterexamples

Earlier I asked a question which showed that $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-n}]$ for $n$ a square free integer greater than 3 is not a UFD.

Since PID implies UFD, this also means $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-n}]$ is not a PID. Is there an example of an ideal in this ring that is not principal?

My earlier question is here [Why is $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-n}], n\ge 3$ not a UFD?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/70976/why-is-mathbbz-sqrt-n-not-a-ufd)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If $R$ is a domain and $p$ is an irreducible that is not a prime, then any witness to the fact that $p$ is not a prime yields a witness to the fact that $R$ is not a PID: suppose that $p|ab$, but $p$ does not divide either $a$ or $b$. Then $(p,a)$ is not principal: if $(p,a)=(x)$, then $x|p$; since $p$ is irreducible, either $x$ is a unit, or $x$ is an associate of $p$.

If $x$ is an associate of $p$, then since $(p,a)=(x)$ we have that $x|a$, hence $p|a$, a contradiction.

If $x$ is a unit, then $(p,a)=(x)=(1)$. Therefore, there exist $\alpha,\beta\in R$ such that $1=\alpha p + \beta a$ (since every element of $(p,a)$ is of the form $rp+sa$ for some $r,s\in R$), hence multiplying through by $b$ gives $b=\alpha b p + \beta ab$, and since $p|ab$, it follows that $p|b$. This is another contradiction.

Thus, $(p,a)$ cannot be principal. Of course, neither can $(p,b)$.

Hence, if $n$ is even and $n\gt 2$, then $(2,\sqrt{-n})$ is not principal in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-n}]$. If $n$ is odd and $n\geq 3$, then $\text{}$$(2,1+\sqrt{-n})$ is not principal.

Comment: By a "domain", I assume you mean what others might refer to as an "integral domain"?

Comment: @goblin The most widely used convention is that integral domains are commutative, and domains are not. On the other hand, the most widely used convention for 'prime' is only defined in a commutative ring, and 'irreducible' is only defined in an integral domain.

Comment: I wanted to verify my understanding of the notation because I have not been exposed to it before now; does $(p,a)$ mean the ideal generated by two elements, namely $p$ and $a$?