# Is $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-3}]$ Euclidean under some other norm?

Tags: ring-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I know that $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-3}]$ is not a Euclidean domain under the usual norm $N(x + y\sqrt{-3}) = x^2 + 3y^2$, but that does not necessarily mean that it can't be a Euclidean domain. Is it possible to define some norm that could make it into a Euclidean domain?

Comment: No, it is not an UFD

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/70976/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It isn't possible. If it were, then $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-3}]$ would be a Unique Factorization Domain. But 
$$4=(2)(2)=(1-\sqrt{-3})(1+\sqrt{-3}),$$
and $2$ and $1\pm\sqrt{-3}$ are non-associate irreducibles.

Alternately, $2$ is irreducible in our ring. But $2$ is not prime, since $2$ divides the product $(1-\sqrt{-3})(1+\sqrt{-3})$, but $2$ divides neither $1-\sqrt{-3}$ nor $1+\sqrt{-3}$.

Comment: @mal Proving that the factors are irreducible in $\rm\:R = \mathbb Z[\sqrt{-3}]\:$ is *not* enough to prove that the factorization is nonunique. It is *essential* to also prove  that $2$ is not associate to $1\pm \sqrt{3}$ in $\rm\:R\:$ (which it *is* in its UFD integral closure $\rm\:R' = \mathbb Z[(1+\sqrt{-3})/2]\:$)

Comment: @Bill Dubuque: The system will not let m delete. How does one take care of that problem?

Comment: No need to delete, just say "*nonassociate* irreducibles" (or say it shows that $2$ is irreducible but not prime, since $\:2\nmid 1\pm\sqrt{3}\:$ in $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-3}]\:).\:$ I emphasized that because many students overlook it.

Comment: @Bill Dubuque: Thanks!

Comment: Is there an example of a ring (of integers) which isn't Euclidean under its standard norm, but which becomes Euclidean under some other norm? I've never thought about this.

Comment: The elements of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{69})$ which are algebraic integers are an example There is a largish literature, fair number of examples, some open problems.

Answer (score 1):

It's also possible to show this by showing that $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-3}]$ is not a principal ideal domain.

If $(2,1+\sqrt{3})$ is principal (this particular ideal is natural to consider after working out why the proof that $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$ is a Euclidean domain breaks down), then if must be either $(1)$ or $(\sqrt{-3})$, because of the modulus of $2$ being small. But if

$1 = 2(a+b\sqrt{-3}) + (1+\sqrt{-3})(c+d\sqrt{-3}) = (2a+c-3d) + (2b+c+d)\sqrt{-3}$

then we can reach a contradiction via a partity argument: $2b+c+d=0$ so $c+d$ is even, so $c-3d$ is even, so the real term in the above $2a+c-3d$ is even. But it's $1$, contradiction.

An almost identical parity argument also shows that $(2,1+\sqrt{-3})\neq(\sqrt{-3})$. So there's a non-principal ideal in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{3}]$, so it can't be a Euclidean domain.

Comment: In the beginning sentence, did you mean $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-3}]?$ As well, did you also mean to state that the parity argument also shows that $(2, 1 + \sqrt{-3}) \neq (\sqrt{-3})$?

Comment: @HaydenOutlaw indeed, fixed (thanks).