# Identifying the quotient ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

I'm trying to apply exactly the same technique as demonstrated in this example from Artin's Algebra -- [image] -- to the ring $\mathbb Z[x]/(5,x^2+3)$. In my case the top arrow from Artin's figure (11.4.6) corresponds to $\mathbb Z[x]\to \mathbb Z, x\mapsto 5$, and the residue of $x^2+3$ is $5^2+3=28$ (which corresponds to Artin's $2^2+1=5$). Shouldn't I get $\mathbb Z_{28}$ then? I was told that this answer isn't correct. But I don't get why I got the wrong answer by following exactly the same process as in Artin's example.

Comment: Why $x\mapsto 5$? It should be $x\mapsto\mathrm i\sqrt3$.

Comment: Oh, I think I see what went wrong then. $\mathbb Z_{28} $ would be isomorphic to $\mathbb Z[x]/(x-5,x^2+3)$.

Comment: Yes, that would make more sense.

Comment: I think that if you write down what $f$ and $g$ are for your example you will see the difference (your quotient involves "killing" $5$ not $x - 5$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Artin's situation and yours are very different.

You can either first kill $5$ and then $x^2+3$ or conversely.

In the former case you first get $\mathbb{F}_5[x]$ and then $\mathbb{F}_{25}$, because the polynomial $x^2+3$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_5$.

If you first kill $x^2+3$, you get $\mathbb{Z}[i\sqrt{3}]$ and here you need to find the quotient modulo the ideal generated by $5$. This adds a few complications, because $\mathbb{Z}[i\sqrt{3}]$ is not a PID, see [Is $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-3}]$ Euclidean under some other norm?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/115934/62967)

Comment: I think the usual way to calculate $\Bbb Z[\sqrt{-3}]/(5)$ is to pass it back to $\Bbb Z[X]/(X^2 + 3, 5)$ and then quotient out $5$ first.

Comment: How is finding the quotient related to the ring not being PID?

Comment: @user660670 You have to prove the ideal is maximal, in order to show that the quotient is a field. Since the ring is not a PID, this is not the same as proving the generator is irreducible.

Comment: @WhatsUp Yes, it's certainly the easier way.