# Algebra. Unique factorization domain.

Tags: abstract-algebra

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-n}]$ not a UFD?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/70976/why-is-mathbbz-sqrt-n-not-a-ufd)

Are $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ and $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-6}]$ UFDs?

I think that $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ is UFD because for example $6=2\cdot3=(1+\sqrt{-5})(1-\sqrt{-5})$ but and $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-6}]$?

Comment: Do you mean $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ and $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-6}]$ ?

Comment: yes, thank for your comment

Comment: You wrote "I think that ... is UFD" and then gave an example of two different factorizations. Did you mean to write "isn't a UFD"? Then the second half of the question is "But and $\Bbb Z[\sqrt{-6}]$?" meaning "what about this other ring?"

Comment: My question is: Is $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-6}]$ a UFD?

Comment: This was asked before for general $\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{-n}]$: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/70976/why-is-mathbbz-sqrt-n-not-a-ufd/70978#70978

Answer (score 1):

$\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-6}]$ is not an UFD since $6=2\cdot 3=-(\sqrt{-6})(\sqrt{-6})$.

Comment: Ok, I see it. The answer is no. Lets consider the number 2. Looking for a factorization of 2 over $ \mathbb{Z}$ we have . Is this factorizartion unique ? If we are looking over another domain like $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-6}]$ , then how easy is to find all the posible factorizations of 2 ? If we find one is it indeed unique?
considering the norm of 2 it's easy. :)

Comment: $2$ is irreducible in $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-6}]$.

Comment: Why do you add the $i$? Why not say $-6=-2\cdot 3=\sqrt{-6}^2$?