# Specific way of showing $\Bbb Z[\sqrt{-d}]$ is not a Euclidean Domain when $d>2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, principal-ideal-domains, integral-domain

Is it true that if a ring is not a UFD then it's not a Euclidean Domain?

**I have a ring $R=\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-d}]=\{ a+b\sqrt{-d} \mid a,b \in \mathbb{Z} \}$ where $d$ is a square free integer. I want to show that it's not a Euclidean domain.**

I have read from [Why is $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{−n}]$ not a UFD?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/70976/why-is-mathbbz-sqrt-n-not-a-ufd) and it makes sense to me. But is there a way to show that it's not a Euclidean domain without using UFD?

EDITED: Thanks @anon for the comment, that way seems very straight forward and I'm sure it is easier than the one I need to do it with. Our professor wanted us to prove it the following way:

First prove that $\delta(z)>0$ if $z\in R$ is not a unit, then prove that there exists a non-unit element $x\in R$ such that $\delta(x) \le \delta(z)$ for every non-unit element $z \in R$, then show that a remainder from the division by $x$ must be a unit in $R$, and that for every $w \in R$ at least one of the three elements $w, w+1$, and $w-1$ must be divisible by $x$ in $R$. Lastly, show that one can pick $w \in \mathbb{Z} \subset R$ such that none of the elements $w$, $w+1$, and $w-1$ is divisible by $x$ in $R$.

And I have no idea how I need to proceed from this.

Comment: Every ED is a UFD. Thus not-UFD implies not-ED. This is called the "contrapositive," it is a very nifty concept from logic to be familiar with. I am curious as to why you would want to prove non-EDness without proving non-UFDness; is it clear there will be a better way?

Comment: Here's a geometric way: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/318543/for-which-d0-is-mathbb-z-sqrtd-an-euclidean-domain?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The method suggested by your professor is sometimes called the *universal side divisor criterion* for showing that a ring in non-Euclidean. The basic idea is quite simple. To prove that a domain is non-Euclidean it suffices to show that it lacks some property possessed by all Euclidean domain. Here this property is that if $x$ is a nonunit of minimal Euclidean value, then, modulo $x$, every element has remainder $0$ or a unit (else the remainder is a nonunit having Euclidean value smaller than $x$, contra hypothesis).

Based on your hint, in your case it seems that the only units of $R$ are $\pm 1$, so every element $w$ has remainder $\,0\,$ or $\,\pm1,\,$ i.e. $x$ divides $w$ or $w\mp1$. It remains to show that there is some $w$ for which this fails, thus completing the proof that $R$ is not Euclidean.

If you google "universal side divisor" you will find some insightful expositions, including worked examples. For example see Keith Conrad's [Remarks about Euclidean domains](http://www.math.uconn.edu/%7Ekconrad/blurbs/ringtheory/euclideanrk.pdf). See also my [answer here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/23872/242) which outlines a proof that $\rm\: \mathbb Z[w],\ w = (1 + \sqrt{-19})/2\ $ is a non-Euclidean PID - based on  sketch by Hendrik W. Lenstra.

Comment: Thanks for the great helps! I have two questions. How will I show that $\delta(z)>0$ if $z$ is not a unit, and for the last step, do I just pick a $w$ that doesn't work then I'll be done? Thanks! Bill Bubuque & @YACP

Comment: @Peter Which specific quadratic ring are you working with?

Comment: $R=\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-d}]=\{ a+b\sqrt{-d} \mid a,b \in \mathbb{Z} \} $ @Bill

Comment: For my first question, is it just because $(a+b\sqrt{-d})(a-b\sqrt{-d})=(a^2+b^2d)$ which is always positive?

Comment: @Peter Generally, Euclidean $\Rightarrow$ UFD, so, conrapositively, non-UFD $\Rightarrow$ non-Euclidean. But usually the proof that such criterion holds cannot be given generally. It requires invoking specific properties of the ring. As such, you should have be given a specific value of $d,$ such as $d = 19$ in the linked posts.

Comment: Thanks. I still don't understand why $\delta(z)>0$ if $z$ is not a unit?

Answer (score 1):

Every Euclidean domain is a UFD, so if a ring is not a UFD, then it is not a Euclidean domain. Note that $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-d}]$ *is* a Euclidean domain for certain values of $d$. See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_domain) for more details.

**Edit** I see you've edited your question. Presumably you want to assume $d > 2$ then.

Comment: thanks, I misread it backwards, just UFD was a subset of ED.