# Proof that $\mathbb{Z}\left[\frac{1 + \sqrt{-19}}{2}\right]$ is a PID

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, principal-ideal-domains

How would one prove that $\mathbb{Z}\left[\frac{1 + \sqrt{-19}}{2}\right]$ is a principal ideal domain (PID)? It isn't a Euclidean domain according to [the Wikipedia article on PIDs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_ideal_domain).

Comment: Read the last example in sec. 8.2 in Dummit&Foote's "Abstract Algebra" . It all boils down to proving that the corresponding field norm is a Dedekind-Hasse norm on this ring and thus it is a PID.

Comment: Ah, very interesting. If you could prove that $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-19})}$ is a Euclidean domain then you don't have to prove that it is a principal ideal domain (PID) because that follows automatically from its being a Euclidean domain.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is a classical example. Here are a few references (out of many) which give a detailed proof.

1.) [An example of a PID that is not a Euclidean Domain](http://www.maths.qmul.ac.uk/%7Eraw/MTH5100/PIDnotED.pdf).

2.) [A principal ideal domain that is not Euclidean](http://math.berkeley.edu/%7Egbergman/grad.hndts/nonEucPID.ps).

3.) [On a Principal Ideal Domain that is not a Euclidean Domain](http://www.m-hikari.com/imf/imf-2013/29-32-2013/wongIMF29-32-2013.pdf).

4.) [Ring of integers is a PID but not a Euclidean domain](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/857971/ring-of-integers-is-a-pid-but-not-a-euclidean-domain).

5.) [An example of a PID that is not a Euclidean Domain](http://www.math.ubc.ca/%7Ereichst/423-project-pid-not-euclidean-siqi-wei.pdf).