# $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1-\sqrt{-19}}{2}]$ - principal ring, but not an euclidean ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I am stucked on the problem. Is there someone who could tell me why $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1-\sqrt{-19}}{2}]$ is a principal ring, but it is not an euclidean ring?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/857971/9464

Comment: http://www.math.ubc.ca/~reichst/423-project-pid-not-euclidean-siqi-wei.pdf

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/998716/9464