# Is there a way of proving that $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ and $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-2}]$ are UFD s without showing that they are euclidian domains?

Tags: abstract-algebra, unique-factorization-domains

What are direct methods for proving that a ring is a UFD in general without proving that it's a PID/Euclidean domain/field and using the fact that all those things are UFDs?

As an example, we can take $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ or $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-2}]$ or other rings you come up with.

Comment: Seems to me that if you're interested in this for some curious reason you might ask first how to show that $\Bbb Z$ is a UFD  by another method... (no,  you don't necessarily see the words "suclidean domain" in the standard proof, but that _is_ how the standard proof for $\Bbb Z$ goes.)

Comment: You might want to look at a PID (hence a UFD) which is not an euclidean domain, like [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/857971/ring-of-integers-is-a-pid-but-not-a-euclidean-domain). Think also about $\Bbb Z[X]$ : it is not euclidean (not even a PID), but it is a UFD (however euclidean divisions by monic polynomials always work).

Answer (score 1):

Here are some thoughts:

- *Exsitence* is easy to prove using induction on the norm.
- *Uniqueness* is the hard part, especially since it fails for most rings of the form $\mathbb Z[\sqrt d]$. For the rings you've mentioned, it can be proved by knowing the units and exactly how primes in $\mathbb Z$ decompose in $\mathbb Z[\sqrt d]$. There are three possibilities for a prime $p$: it remains prime, it is product of two non associate primes, it is a square. For the rings you've mentioned, this can be decided in ad hoc ways.

In the general case of the [ring of integers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_integer) in quadratic fields $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{n})$, the answer is not simple but is fascinating, See the book [*Primes of the Form $x^2+ny^2$*](http://www.cs.amherst.edu/~dac/primes.html), by David Cox.

Answer (score -1):

This would be extremely wasteful, and nobody would do it before showing they were Euclidean domains or PIDs, but you could show that they have class number 1 through some indirect means. $\mathbb Z[i]$ is a Dedekind domain so it is a UFD if and only if its class number is 1.

Comment: What about UFD s that aren't even PID s?

Comment: That's a god question, and I'm not sure there's a general method. I mean, there are things like that if $R$ is a UFD, then so is $R[x]$, but that's not useful in many circumstances.