# For which $d \in \mathbb{Z}$ is $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}]$ a unique factorization domain?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, unique-factorization-domains

Is there a general criterion which tells me whether $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}]$, $d \in \mathbb{Z}$ is a unique factorization domain?

$\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ is a frequent example for non-unique factorization domains because 6 has two different factorizations. $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-1}]$ on the other hand is a Euclidean domain. But I'm not even sure about simple examples like $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$.

Comment: I believe it's not even known whether there are infinitely many. At least when $d$ is squarefree and $d\equiv 2,3\bmod 4$, we have
$$\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}]=\text{ring of integers of }\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$$
and then it's a question of what the class number of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$ is ([Wikipedia link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_number_fields_with_class_number_one)).

Comment: See also [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/321276/for-which-d-is-mathbb-z-sqrt-d-a-principal-ideal-domain?rq=1).

Comment: Interesting. So it is known for which negative integers it is true but not for which positive integers?

Comment: Yes. Note, though, that it's more usual to consider the ring of integers of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$ rather than $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}]$ -- the former is the integral closure of the latter inside $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d}$). Assuming $d$ is squarefree, this agrees when $d$ isn't $1$ mod $4$, but for $d\equiv 1 \pmod{4}$ the former is slightly larger. In this case, $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}]$ cannot possibly be a UFD, as it isn't integrally closed in its fraction field. Which could be taken as one reason why we look at the ring of integers instead, which could be.

Comment: A ring of algebraic integers is a UFD if an only if it is principal. Moreover $\mathbf Z[\sqrt d]$ is a ring of algebraic integers, for a square-free $d$ if and only id $d\not\equiv 1\mod 4$. If $d<0$, there are only $9$ values for which its a PID.

Comment: @Harry: I'm not familiar with the concept of the integral closure. Could you make an easy example where I can see your point?

Comment: I'd just look up what the other commenters have already written (see in particular [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_integer)). But basically, to be brief, to say that a ring $A$ is integrally closed in its fraction field $K$ means that for any monic polynomial over $A$, all its roots in $K$ in fact lie in $A$. That this is true for the integers is known as the Rational Root Theorem; the same proof works for UFDs in general.

Comment: This link may be of some help: http://oeis.org/A061574

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The general criterion is that no number can be found with more than one valid, distinct factorization. This might sound like I'm merely rephrasing the question, but it's actually a reframing of the question.

Plenty of numbers (infinitely many, to be precise) in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ have more than one factorization. $6$ is just the easiest to find. To oversimplify matters, your main concern is with the "natural" primes from 2 to $p < 4|d|$ or $p \leq d$ as needed.

Now, the case of $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$ is actually more complicated than you might realize. Part of the complication is that $\sqrt{2}$ is a real number and so $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$ has infinitely many units. This sets up the trap of infinitely many factorizations that are not distinct because they involve multiplication by units, e.g., $$7 = (3 - \sqrt{2})(3 + \sqrt{2}) = (-1)(1 - 2\sqrt{2})(1 + 2\sqrt{2}) = (5 - 3\sqrt{2})(5 + 3\sqrt{2}) = \ldots$$

But $7$ really does have only one distinct factorization in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$, as you can see by dividing these numbers by $1 + \sqrt{2}$, and $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$ really is a UFD. But the full explanation may require me to make several assumptions about what you know.

Let's look at a "simpler" domain, $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{10}]$, though it certainly has some of the same traps as $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$: $$31 = (-1)(3 - 2\sqrt{10})(3 + 2\sqrt{10}) = (11 - 3\sqrt{10})(11 + 3\sqrt{10}) = (-1)(63 - 20\sqrt{10})(63 \ldots$$

You have to look at numbers that are already composite in $\mathbb{Z}$ to begin with. And if $d = pq$, where $p$ and $q$ are distinct primes, the choice of where to look first is obvious: $$10 = 2 \times 5 = (\sqrt{10})^2.$$

Verify that $$\frac{\sqrt{10}}{2} \not\in \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{10}], \frac{\sqrt{10}}{5} \not\in \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{10}], \frac{2}{\sqrt{10}} \not\in \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{10}], \frac{5}{\sqrt{10}} \not\in \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{10}].$$ This means that $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{10}]$ is *not* UFD and we didn't need to compute any logarithms or sines to come to this conclusion. (You're starting to see why integral closure matters in making these determinations, right?)

Contrast $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{6}]$: $$6 = (2 - \sqrt{6})(2 + \sqrt{6})(3 - \sqrt{6})(3 + \sqrt{6}) = (\sqrt{6})^2$$ but $$\frac{\sqrt{6}}{2 + \sqrt{6}} = 3 - \sqrt{6}$$ and so on and so forth. This means that $6 = (\sqrt{6})^2$ is an incomplete factorization, just as, say, $81 = 9^2$ is in $\mathbb{Z}$. But this is not enough to prove that $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{6}]$ is or is not UFD.

As it turns out, both $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$ and $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{6}]$ are UFDs, and what is probably the simplest, most common way of proving this requires a full understanding of ideals. Adapting the proof that $\mathbb{Z}$ is a UFD to these domains can be done, but that has its own pitfalls.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is. But first there is the matter of integral closure (I prefer to think of it as "completeness") to attend to. If $d \equiv 1 \pmod 4$, then you need $\frac{1 + \sqrt{d}}{2}$ instead of $d$. For example, with $d = 13$, $1 + \sqrt{13}$ is an algebraic integer, but so is $\frac{1 + \sqrt{13}}{2}$. For fun, try this in your calculator: $$\left(\frac{1 - \sqrt{13}}{2}\right)\left(\frac{1 + \sqrt{13}}{2}\right) = ?$$

---

The criterion is $h(4d) = 1$ if $d \not \equiv 1 \pmod 4$, $h(d) = 1$ if so. $h(d)$ is a function that tells you the class number of $\mathcal{O}_{\textbf{Q}(\sqrt{d})}$. I now quote the formula for $h(d)$ from Mathworld: if $d$ is positive, $$h(d) = -\frac{1}{2 \log \eta(d)} \sum_{r = 1}^{d - 1} \left(\frac{d}{r}\right) \log \sin \left(\frac{\pi r}{d}\right),$$ see http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ClassNumber.html for a full explanation of this, make sure to substitute $4d$ as needed. That also gives the formula for $d$ negative, but since there are only nine such values...

Comment: I would hate to try to compute this by hand, even for $\sqrt{10}$, i.e. $d=40$.

Comment: That's a good point. In my haste to crank out the answer I didn't have to time to get a sense of how often preliminary calculations would clearly show $h > 1$, making it unnecessary to complete the calculation.