# Properties of rings of the form $\mathbb{Z}+\mathbb{Z}\sqrt{p}i+\mathbb{Z}\sqrt{q}j+\mathbb{Z}\sqrt{r}k$

Tags: abstract-algebra, unique-factorization-domains, euclidean-domain

It is well-known that $\mathbb{Z}+\mathbb{Z}\sqrt{5}i$ is not a unique factorization domain, since, for example, $6$ has two different factorizations into irreducibles:  $(1+\sqrt{5}i)(1-\sqrt{5}i)=2\cdot3$.

Let $p,q,r \in \mathbb{N}$ be odd primes (not necessarily three different).
Perhaps we should also require that each of $\{p,q,r\}$ is congruent to $1$ mod $4$ (perhaps no).

Let $R_{p,q,r}:=\mathbb{Z}+\mathbb{Z}\sqrt{p}i+\mathbb{Z}\sqrt{q}j+\mathbb{Z}\sqrt{r}k$, where $i^2=j^2=k^2=-1$, $ij=k$ etc., as in the [quaternions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion) (replacing $\mathbb{R}$ by $\mathbb{Z}$).

Trivially, $R_{p,q,r}$ is an integral domain, because it is a subset of $\mathbb{C}$.

Of course,$R_{p,q,r}$ is not a UFD, since, for example, $(1-\sqrt{p}i)(1+\sqrt{p}i)=1-pi^2=1+p=1+(1+4u)=2+4u=2(1+2u)$.

> What else can be said about those integral domains?

**For example:** I guess that $R_{p,q,r}$ is a [Euclidean domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_domain), isn't it? Is there a known proof for this or one just needs  to adjust the proof for $\mathbb{Z}+\mathbb{Z}\sqrt{5}i$?

[This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1319146/for-which-d-in-mathbbz-is-mathbbz-sqrtd-a-unique-factorization-do?rq=1) question is relevant.

Any hints and comments are welcome!

Comment: For the tensor product of this thing with a field see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion_algebra .

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, thank you very much for your comment.

Comment: Something's wrong here @cactus314. $R_{p,q,r}$ is not even a ring. Say, $p=5$, $q=13$, $r=17$, then
$$(\sqrt{5}i)(\sqrt{13}j)=\sqrt{65}k\notin R_{5,13,17}.$$

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, thank you for your important comment. (I apologize for the delay).