# For which $d$, the algebraic integers of $K =\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt d)$ is a PID?

Tags: reference-request, field-theory, principal-ideal-domains, algebraic-integers

I know that the matter is settled for $d<0$ and an open problem for $d>0$ but I am asking about already known values. The below theorems are the motivation for asking this question.

> Let $d$ be a square-free integer such that $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt d]$ is a PID and $q$ be an
> odd prime such that $$(d \mid q) =1 $$ Then there exist integers $u,v$ such that $$q = 
>   \mid u^2 - dv^2 \mid $$

and

> Let $d = 1 \pmod 4$ be a squarefree integer such that $\mathbb{Z}\left[ \frac{1 + \sqrt d}{2}\right]$ is a PID and $q$ be an odd prime such that $(d \mid q)=1$ then there exist integers $u,v$ such that $$ q = \left|  \left(u + \frac v2 \right)^2 - \frac{mv^2}{4} \right| $$

where $(. \mid .)$ is the Legendre's symbol.

So knowing the values of $d$ for which $O_K$ is a PID will be a great advantage in representing primes in quadratic forms. So here I list some of the values that I know.

- [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/450017/826797) answer lists all the values for
  $d<0$ and they are $d=-1, -2 , -3 , -7, -11, -19, -43, -67,$ or $-163$.
- In the book Introductory Algebraic number theory by S.Alaca , K.Williams, we can see
  examples of norm Euclidean domains (so PID) and they are for $d = 
     2,3,5,6,7,11,13,17,19,21,29,33,37,41,57,$ or $ 73$.
- In the same book we also see that the authors mentioning that for $d  =  14,69$ are also
  Euclidean hence PID.

Are there any other values of $d$ that are known in the literature? It will be great if you can add some references along with your answer at least.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot give a comprehensive list, nor point you at published articles/books. My "go to" -source for bits like these is the LMF-database.

> [This query](http://www.lmfdb.org/NumberField/?hst=List&degree=2&class_number=1&search_type=List) says that the database contains 177168 matches to my search criteria of number fields of degree two and class number one.

Caveat: I am not very experienced in interpreting the database output.

Comment: This is only a comment. But it may actually answer the question so I made it a CW-answer instead.

Comment: ^Should have emphasized the point that the answer may say something that has not been covered on this site earlier.

Comment: The database which you mentioned is very helpful