# Why $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-3}]$ is not a Euclidean domain?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, ring-theory

I need to prove that $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-3}]$ is not a Euclidean domain. I tried to show that $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-3}]$ is not  a P.I.D. but all ideals that I generate by *two* elements, turn out to be principal.

I already appreciate your help in advance.

Comment: What is your definition of a Euclidean domain?

Comment: @Alizter http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_domain

Comment: $\mathbf{Z}[(1 + \sqrt{-3})/2]$ *is* a Euclidean domain. Try focusing on the difference between the two rings.

Comment: You can try to show it is not a UFD. The solution is here after you try it: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/70976/why-is-mathbbz-sqrt-n-not-a-ufd

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hint:

$$\left(1-\sqrt3\,i\right)\left(1+\sqrt3\,i\right)=4=2\cdot 2$$

Now just show $\;2\;$ is not associate with $\;1\pm\sqrt3\,i\;$ and you get your ring is not a UFD.