# Proof of No Unique Factorisation in $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{d}]$ for $d \leq-3$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, unique-factorization-domains

> How would I prove there is no unique factorisation in $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{d}]$ for $d \leq-3$, where $d$ is a square-free integer?

I think it's something to do with the only invertible elements being $\pm 1$

Comment: I believe this is wrong.

Comment: Yes, wrong for $d=-4$.

Comment: oops I should say that d is square free

Comment: squarefree is still not enough,   http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1211145/for-which-values-of-d0-is-the-subring-of-quadratic-integers-of-mathbb-q

Comment: @WillJagy The ring of integers is different from $Z[\sqrt{d}]$ for $d\equiv 1 \bmod 4$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde, alright. Given the apparent peculiarity here, I would like to know the source of the problem and what has been done in class prior to this exercise.  Where was I: if you mean that squarefree IS good enough, I can accept that.

Comment: yeah I just realised I forgot to mention d is odd. sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $d$ is even, then $2$ divides $\sqrt{d}^2=d$, but does not divide $\sqrt{d}$ for $d\le -3$ and $d$ squarefree, so $2$ is irreducible but not prime, which is impossible in a UFD. 
Similarly, if $d$ is odd, then $2$ divides $(1+\sqrt{d})(1-\sqrt{d})=1-d$ without dividing either of the factors, so again $2$ is a nonprime irreducible.