# Example of integral domain which is not a UFD

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, integral-domain, unique-factorization-domains

I was looking for an integral domain which is not a UFD and I've thought to

$\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(x-y^2)$

My questions are:

Is it right?

Is there any easier example?

Comment: That's isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}[x]$. You can take $\mathbb{C}[x, y]/(x^2 - y^3)$ although it takes a little effort to actually prove that this works.

Comment: Ok, to be clear. I though to write $y^2$ both as $y \cdot y$ that as $x$ but in the quotient $x$ is not more irreducible. Is it right? Now, to prove your state,  it is sufficient to prove that, in the quotient $x$ and $y$ are still irreducible, isn't it?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3016671/when-are-quadratic-rings-of-integers-unique-factorization-domains gives you a nice class of such rings.

Comment: [DaRT query](https://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/search/results/?H=1&H=8&L=114) for commutative domains that aren't UFDs.