# Find integers solutions of $x^2+7=y^5$

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

I have the following problem: 
find the integers solutions of equation
$$
x^2+7=y^5 \;.
$$

Could someone help with this, please?

**My approach:**

After applying usual idea considering this equation in ring $Z[\alpha]$, where $\alpha$ is a root of  $x^2-x+3=0$, I obtained that 
$(x-\sqrt{-7})=(a+b \alpha)^5$, for some $a$, $b$ $\in$ $Z[\alpha]$. 
After equaling coefficient of $\sqrt{-7}$, I got: 
$$
32=5a^4b-70a^2b-49b^5 \;,
$$
and I don't know how to find such pairs.

Comment: see here https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/S0017089500031918 i hope this will help you

Comment: Also, it appears that you have $x^2-25=y^5-32$, FWIW.

Comment: you will get $$x\pm 5$$ and $$y=2$$

Comment: You appear to be assuming that $\mathbb Z[\sqrt {-7}]$ is a ufd, which is not the case.  See, e.g., [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/70976/why-is-mathbbz-sqrt-n-n-ge-3-not-a-ufd)

Comment: Yes, but I work in $Z[\alpha]$, not in $Z[\sqrt{-7}]$, where I have ufd.

Comment: Well...Unless I have messed it up (definitely possible) your second equation has no solutions, so something seems awry.  I deleted my post which shows (I think) that your second equation has no solutions.  Can you see the deleted post?

Comment: In case you can't see the deleted solution, it is this:  we see that $b\,|\,32$.  Work $\pmod 5$ to see that $b=5k+2$ which implies $b=2,32$.  Now work $\pmod 7$ to eliminate both.

Comment: nope, I can't, could you post , please.

Comment: I'll undelete for now.

Comment: Thank you, it seems that there is a mistake in my approach, because there is a solution as mentioned above.

Comment: Well, either that or there's a mistake in what I wrote.  One suggestion:  go through your calculation and find the pair $(a,b)$ attached to the solution $(5,2)$.  If you can produce a viable $(a,b)$ then obviously I blundered.

Comment: I don't understand why nobody has noticed that $\alpha = \frac{1}{2}(1+ \sqrt{-11})$ yet, so that $\sqrt{-7} \notin Z[ \alpha ]$. Does this make sense?

Comment: @Crostul  Indeed.  The logic of the question really appears based in $\mathbb Z[\sqrt {-7}]$.

Comment: @user44636  I am re-deleting my post.  There is an error, in that I assume that $b>0$.  If we allow $b<0$ then $b=-8$ works $\pmod 5$ and the resulting congruence $\pmod 7$ does have a solution.

Comment: @Crostul It seems likely to me that that's a typo. $x^2+x-2$ is the correct minimal polynomial of $\alpha=(-1+\sqrt{-7})/2$. (Correction: it should have been $x^2-x+2$, and $\alpha=(1+\sqrt{-7})/2$)

Comment: @lulu $\Bbb{Z}[\alpha]$ is the ring of integers of $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{-7})$, and it [is a UFD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heegner_number). Oops. Sorry, this was already pointed out.

Comment: Yes. Correct, @peterag (noticed my error during a trip to the fridge:-)

Comment: Thanks to everyone for fixing mistakes, but what about solution? Any ideas?

Comment: Interesting question. Note that $x$ must be odd, and that there are no solutions with $y\leq2\times10^7$ other that $(x,y)=(\pm5,2)$ and $(x,y)=(\pm181,8)$. Also SAGE returns only these four solutions, and no others.

Answer (score 0):

A hint has been already been given to rearrange the equation as,
$$(x-5)(x+5)=(y-2)(y^4+2y^3+4y^2+8y+16)$$
and the solutions $(x,y)=(\pm 5,2)$ already found.

There is another solution, $(x,y)=(\pm 181,8)$, which I found with just a spreadsheet; sorry but I cannot justify this other than $176*186=6*5456$, as much of your maths is above my understanding

I’ve thrown together code and checked up to $y=602248$ but found no other solutions.