# Embedding $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-3}]$ in a larger ring

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm struggling with the following question:

Show how $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-3}]$ may be embedded as a subring in a larger ring R, which is a PID, with the quotient of additive groups having index 2.

I've tried $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-3}]+\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{3}]$ among other things but not sure if I'm on the right track.

Comment: $1,\sqrt3$ and $\sqrt{-3}$ are linearly independent over $\Bbb{Z}$, so your suggestion cannot work. The index of a lower rank free abelian group is automatically infinite.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen - I don't know that the OP wanted the answer, or a hint? (This is often an issue, isn't it, in this type of question...)

Comment: @peterag That is, indeed, a recurring problem. I only gave it in a comment, for I suspect this question is actually a duplicate (in a wider sense of the word).

Comment: Anyway, the sought after ring is called [Eisensteinian integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein_integer). Too famous not to have been covered.

Comment: May be a good answer here would be to first explain why this ring is not a PID, and then explain how to fix that :-/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [integral closure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_element#Integral_closure) of $\Bbb Z$ in $\Bbb{Q}\left(\sqrt{-3}\right)$ is the larger ring $\Bbb Z\left[\frac{1 + \sqrt{-3}}{2}\right]$, since $-3 \equiv 1 \bmod{4}$. This is norm-Euclidean and in particular a PID. For $d\equiv 2,3 \bmod 4$, $d$ squarefree the integral closure of $\Bbb Z$ in $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$ is equal to $\Bbb Z[\sqrt{d}]$.

Edit: It would be useful to see that $\Bbb Z[\sqrt{-3}]$ is not a PID, see Jyrki's comment. Indeed, this is not even an UFD:

[Why is $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-n}], n\ge 3$ not a UFD?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/70976/why-is-mathbbz-sqrt-n-n-ge-3-not-a-ufd?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: it is norm euclidean [because](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein_integer#Euclidean_domain) $\sqrt{3}/2 < 1$

Comment: @reuns $\Bbb Z[\omega]$ is norm-Euclidean, but not $\Bbb Z[\sqrt{-3}]$. I assume with "it" you mean the ring of Eisenstein integers?