# why its fail at n = $1$ and $2$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

i have some  confusion in this  answer

[Why is $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-n}], n\ge 3$ not a UFD?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/70976/why-is-mathbbz-sqrt-n-n-ge-3-not-a-ufd)

My  confusion is
[image]

My attempt :  we know that  $1$ is odd and $2$ is  even  . So  if $n$ is even then $n=2$ , then obviously  $2$ divides $\sqrt{-2}^2=-2$ but does not divide $\sqrt{-2}$, so $2$ is a nonprime irreducible

Again  similarly take $n =1$ when $n$ is odd ,$2$ divides $(1+\sqrt{-1})(1-\sqrt{-1})=1+1=2$ without dividing either of the factors, so again $2$ is a nonprime irreducible.

But the user chris eagle  said that  it fail for $n= 1, 2$

why  is fail for $n =1 , 2 $??

Comment: Doesn’t $2=(1+\sqrt{-1})(1-\sqrt{-1}) =-\sqrt{-2}^2$ show $2$ is reducible in $\Bbb Z[\sqrt{-1}$ and

Comment: @J.W.Tanner $ 2 $ does not  divide $ ( 1+ \sqrt {-1})$

Comment: I meant $\Bbb Z[\sqrt{-1}]$ and $\Bbb Z[\sqrt{-2}]$, respectively?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your argument is that $2$ is actually reducible in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-2}]$, as $2=(-\sqrt{-2})\sqrt{-2}$. So there is no problem with it being not prime.

Similarly, in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ we have $2=(1+i)(1-i)$, so again it is reducible.

Comment: ....@Mark   But $1+ i $ is  an irreducible  element of $\mathbb{Z}[i]$  How  it is reducible ?

Comment: $1+i$ is irreducible, but why is that important? I'm saying $2$ is reducible as it is a product of two non-invertible elements.

Comment: oh soorry @Mark u