# Finding GCD of two elements over a quadratic extension of integers

Tags: extension-field, gcd-and-lcm

I'm asking for a step-by-step explanation on finding $GCD(1+\sqrt{13}, 5+2\sqrt{13})$ in $\mathbb{Z}\left[\frac{1+\sqrt{13}}{2}\right]$.

Comment: Do you know how to perform a *Euclidean division* in this ring?

Comment: Let $a = \frac{1+\sqrt{13}}{2}$ 
 note $a (a-1) = 3$ so that

$(2a,3+4a) = (3,2a)=(a)(a-1,2)= (a)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\Bbb{Z}[\frac{1+\sqrt{13}}{2}]$ is Norm  Euclidean (see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/58563/254075) and the references given there), so we can apply the Euclidean algorithm to find the GCD.
$$\begin{align}
5+2\sqrt{13}&= 2(1+\sqrt{13}) +3 \\
1+\sqrt{13}&= -1\cdot 3 +(4+\sqrt{13}) \\
3 &= (4-\sqrt{13})(4+\sqrt{13}) + 0
\end{align}$$
So we see $4+\sqrt{13}$ is the GCD (up to associates) and $\dfrac{1+\sqrt{13}}{4+\sqrt{13}}=-3+\sqrt{13}$ and $\dfrac{5+2\sqrt{13}}{4+\sqrt{13}}=-2+\sqrt{13}$